# No job routing in cups

Tags: printer, printing, routing, network-printer

I have just bought a new printer Lexmark C950de and i have instal a hardisk of 320 GB in it.

I have in the past configure printer HP to do job storage from cups but now on Lexmark printer, i don't have job storage in cups but when i try to print, i have the option for job routing which is like job storage but the problem is that i can not save the configuration of all job to do job routing as i don't see it in cups.

Is there another way , which i can do so as all my job goes to the printer and store in the hardisk and then i select to print.

Thanks for helping me.

Abhi

Answer (score 0):

Most printers do not let you store print jobs on the hard disk. [According to Lexmark](http://www.lexmark.com/en_ZA/products/memory/27X0014.shtml), a hard disk is used to "buffer print jobs, collate large jobs or to store forms, fonts or macros." Buffering is not the same as storing - it's just temporary storage as and when needed by the printer, for example when collating jobs that are too large to fit in memory.

Some printers support "[secure printing](http://www.fujixeroxprinters.com.hk/en/products/colourprinters/phaser6700dn.aspx)", where a job is held on disk until a password is entered at the printer, but Lexmark does not seem to have that feature either.